# Compare strings by comparing words checking only the same number of letters in the word

Tags: java

Given:

```java
String s0 = "we wrocławiu"
String s1 = "w warszawie"
```

When:

```java
Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("pl", "PL"));
collator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
collator.setDecomposition(Collator.FULL_DECOMPOSITION);
int result = collator.compare(s0, s1);
```

Then:

```java
assertTrue(result < 0);
```

But the result > 0.

How to compare strings to ignore the letter `e`? So if it compares word with 3 letters to word with 5 letters it should only check 3 letters.

Comment: So, are you trying to ask "how to compare two strings, truncated so that each word in the string is the same length"?

Comment: yes. In SQL COLLATE function is enough to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

**Pseudo code:**

```java
// Find the length of the string which has the smallest length

// Truncate the other string so that they have both the same lengths

// Compare them
```